# MYSQL query better way to group by if values?

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a working query, but there has to be a better way to do this. 
Here is the working query

```
SELECT gameid FROM(
    SELECT gameid, SUM(count) as total FROM (
        SELECT IF(vanguard = 1, 30, gameid) as gameid, count FROM (
            SELECT opserv_operation.gameid, opserv_games.vanguard, COUNT(opserv_games.gameid) AS count FROM opserv_operation_attendees INNER JOIN opserv_operation ON opserv_operation_attendees.operationid = opserv_operation.operationid INNER JOIN opserv_games on opserv_operation.gameid = opserv_games.gameid WHERE (start_time >= '2015-11-11' || FIND_IN_SET(opserv_operation.operationid, '17951,17701,17702,17775,17969,17890,17958,17966,17900')) AND completed = 1 AND opserv_operation_attendees.userid = 5750 AND opserv_operation_attendees.status = 4 AND opserv_operation.type <> 5 AND opserv_operation.completed = 1 GROUP BY opserv_operation.gameid) as m
        ) as l 
    GROUP BY gameid
    ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1) as k
```

The main query

```
SELECT opserv_operation.gameid, opserv_games.vanguard, COUNT(opserv_games.gameid) AS count FROM opserv_operation_attendees INNER JOIN opserv_operation ON opserv_operation_attendees.operationid = opserv_operation.operationid INNER JOIN opserv_games on opserv_operation.gameid = opserv_games.gameid WHERE (start_time >= '2015-11-11' || FIND_IN_SET(opserv_operation.operationid, '17951,17701,17702,17775,17969,17890,17958,17966,17900')) AND completed = 1 AND opserv_operation_attendees.userid = 5750 AND opserv_operation_attendees.status = 4 AND opserv_operation.type <> 5 AND opserv_operation.completed = 1 GROUP BY opserv_operation.gameid
```

gameid vanguard
16  0
36  1
36  1
36  1
16  0
36  1
27  0
16  0
36  1
36  1
36  1
30  0
36  1
36  1
27  0
36  1
36  1
36  1

So here is the tricky part. I need it to group by and count all the values however if gameid = 30 or vanguard = 1 then they should be all counted together.

So with the above data, the only thing I need is the gameid returned in this case gameid 30. It would have the most counts which would be 13.

There has to be a better way than I have done it.

Edit: So far this one works great thanks to Ed Gibbs. However is still returns two values, I'm guessing only way is to have another subquery? to get just gameid.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN vanguard = 1 THEN 30 ELSE gameid END AS gameid,
SUM(count) AS total
FROM (SELECT opserv_operation.gameid, opserv_games.vanguard, COUNT(opserv_games.gameid) AS count FROM opserv_operation_attendees INNER JOIN opserv_operation ON opserv_operation_attendees.operationid = opserv_operation.operationid INNER JOIN opserv_games on opserv_operation.gameid = opserv_games.gameid WHERE (start_time >= '2015-11-11' || FIND_IN_SET(opserv_operation.operationid, '17951,17701,17702,17775,17969,17890,17958,17966,17900')) AND completed = 1 AND opserv_operation_attendees.userid = 5750 AND opserv_operation_attendees.status = 4 AND opserv_operation.type <> 5 AND opserv_operation.completed = 1 GROUP BY opserv_operation.gameid) as l
GROUP BY CASE WHEN vanguard = 1 THEN 30 ELSE gameid END
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bottom line you mean "1" and "30" have to be counted together then this should work:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN vanguard = 1 THEN 30 ELSE gameid END AS gameid
FROM (... main query ...)
GROUP BY CASE WHEN gameid = 1 THEN 30 ELSE gameid END
ORDER BY SUM(count) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: This is very close. I changed gameid = 1 to vanguard = 1 and put my main query in brackets in place of from opserv_operation. But its returning 2 values still, gameid and total. and I need it to just do game id. Is the only way to get just game id is to do another subquery?

Comment: Sorry about the "gameid" vs "vanguard"; glad you picked up the pieces :) You can order by the SUM without making it part of the `SELECT` list - it's shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance! I actually learned something.